# Crawling User Profiles - 'A component required for crawling...'

Tags: user-profile, 2016, enterprise-search

I have a SharePoint 2016 single server farm set up and updated to latest CU (June 2018) I have set up my user profile and search services which are all working fine, however, when I try to crawl my user profiles using sps3s:// I get an error in the crawl (site is set up over SSL) and the users do not show up in results:

```
'A component required for crawling this type of content is not registered with this application server'
```

ULS Error:

```
CMatrixHandler::CreateAccessor failed for sps3s://profiles.dev-sharepoint.com, CT=  [matrixhandler.cxx:157]  search\native\gather\protocols\sps2\matrixhandler.cxx
```

As this is a single server farm all search components are installed on the same server.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. I think is related to the July Windows Update because it started to happen exactly the day they were installed

- https://redmondmag.com/articles/2018/07/27/microsoft-patches-sql-server-failures.aspx
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/4345913/access-denied-errors-after-installing-july-2018-security-rollup-update

I have applied some of those patches without luck yet. I'll update here if I find a solution, but maybe this can help you in the right direction and you solve it first!

UPDATE:

It's working now on my farm. I installed KB4338831 and KB4346406 (I have 2012R2 and SP2016, framework 4.7.2, check out on the links the exact KB you need).

I guess it might be enough to install KB4346406 but it doesn't seem to hurt so far having both of them.

I hope it solves your problem too.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like its probably the issue, its a dev environment and I didn't turn off windows updates so chances are it installed itself. I will apply those KB and if it works update this thread :)

Comment: Huge thanks, I was running Windows Server 2016 so I just installed KB4346877, after it was installed I re ran crawl and everything is working as it should.